# Issue interacting with Internet Explorer ComObject on Server 2008 R2

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, object, powershell, comobject

Ok, so I have written a pretty intense PowerShell script that installs and configures SharePoint 2007 and SQL 2008. That is what it is, please don't judge me. After finishing all of that up, because the script is supposed to be user friendly, I developed a web form to gather inputs and display task progress. Stupidly, I wrote all the code for the web form on Windows 8.1 without even testing the basic functions on Server 2008 R2 where the script will be executed. When I took the code over to the server, it malfunctioned pretty much immediately. When I then tested it on Windows 7, it worked fine.

Here is the behavior on Windows 8.1 (w/ IE 11) and Windows 7 (w/ IE 9):

```
>$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
>$ie.Navigate('about:blank')
>$ie.visible = $true #Internet explorer is now displayed with a blank page
>$ie.document


Script                            : System.__ComObject
all                               : System.__ComObject
body                              : System.__ComObject
activeElement                     : System.__ComObject
images                            : System.__ComObject
applets                           : System.__ComObject
links                             : System.__ComObject
forms                             : System.__ComObject
anchors                           : System.__ComObject
title                             :
scripts                           : System.__ComObject
designMode                        : Inherit
selection                         : System.__ComObject
readyState                        : complete
```

The list goes on for a while....

Now when I run the same code on Server 2008 R2:

```
>$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
>$ie.Navigate('about:blank')
>$ie.visible = $true #Internet explorer is now displayed with a blank page
>$ie.document
System.__ComObject
```

This is a little bit of a problem as the script pretty heavily relies on writing to and reading from the IE Document object and none of the classes I need are available. Rather no classes are available, even the ones I don't need.

So is there any way to access the document object on Server 2008 R2? I have gone through everything that I can think of with the security zone settings (although I may have missed something there), and I have disabled the enhanced security configuration and the IE protected mode. Nothing I have done seems to give me access to the document. Any advice?

Comment: Is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197141/internetexplorer-application-com-object-and-windows-2012-in-powershell

Comment: @NathanRice there isn't any error. PowerShell just returns what the OP has posted.

Comment: @DeanOC Unfortunately that is not really of any help. I have tried loading the module manually and even got my hands on the visual studio tools to load Microsoft.mshtml.dll into the GAC. Neither of those tasks resolved my issue. Of note, however, the Windows 7 system that it works on does not have .net isntalled or any of the primary interop assemblies..

Comment: Ok, so a little update: I have actually been doing things differently. On the Windows 7 and 8.1 machines I have been running PowerShell without elevated permissions and on the Server 2008 R2 machine, because I need the elevated permissions to install the software, I have been running PowerShell as admin. So the problem now is that the document object is available when running as a user, but still unavailable when running as admin.

Comment: Ok, turns out I'm a moron. While the solution in the link you sent me did not work, I had actually succeeded in deploying Microsoft.mshtml.dll into the GAC using gacutil.exe. The reason it was not working on my administrative PowerShell was because I had not restarted the PowerShell instance after deploying the assembly. To get around this for purposes of the script, I have included the operation as part of the batch wrapper for my script before PowerShell is even loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by deploying the Microsoft.mshtml.dll assembly from the Windows 8.1 machine to the GAC on the Server 2008 R2 machine using gacutil.exe and restarting the PowerShell instance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may allow you to still have an HTML but not use if in PowerShell is write an HTA, and export all of the required values from the .hta to a .csv file, and then import those values from the .csv to your Windows PowerShell prompt. Not the cleanest solution by any means, but it's much easier than XAML / WPF, and is available on more platforms. The only draw back may be that I don't know if Windows Server supports HTA. If it doesn't, a simple workaround might be to run the parameter export piece on a client computer, with the actual installation on the server.

Another route might be using the PowerShell script to run the commands against the server, while running the front-end on a client computer. I know that Invoke-Command will let you run against the server, but simultaneously grant you the ability to use IE.

Sorry I can't give more advice, but I've never tried doing this on Windows Server before.

Comment: If I was using this for any other purpose than installing SharePoint 2007, I probably would have gone the route of running the commands against the server. However, while the actual installation may have succeeded, the configuration piece would not. SharePoint 2007 does not support PowerShell and remotely executing commands through PSRemoting or old-school psexec fails for some reason. This is a bug that has pained me for years on countless installations. PSCONFIG.EXE and STSADM.EXE simply do not like to be executed remotely.